# How can I save an email before delivering to virtual users in Postfix?

Tags: postfix

I'm using Postfix with DBMail, so Postfix delivers emails to virtual users. It has been working perfectly.

However, I want to save all emails to a local disk before delivering to virtual users. I found that content_filter can do that, but it's not a good way for me because I've already used it for spam filtering with DSpam.

Is there an another way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Beware of the legal traps you might fall into..

Comment: pauska, I'm implementing a mail archive system.

Answer (score 2):

I've done something very similar; there seem to be a couple of different approaches.

First off, you could use `recipient_bcc_maps` to generate an additional address for incoming mail to that domain. This could be, for example, a table to say if the email has a recipient `foo@ourdomain.example.com` it should be bcc'd to `archive`, which is then aliased to a file/maildir.

Alternatively, the way I've done it locally is by having entries like this in my "virtual" (`virtual_mailbox_maps`) table:

```
supply@emails.example.com           supply@emails.example.com, offline-comms
```

and then in my "vmailbox" (`virtual_mailbox_maps`) table:

```
supply@emails.example.com           supply/
```

I then have `virtual_mailbox_base` set up to be the base directory of my mail archives. The entry in the "virtual" table splits the incoming email to `supply@emails.example.com` into a delivery to `offline-comms` (which feeds the email to the application servers) and also to itself, so it gets looked up in "vmailbox" as well. The "vmailbox" entry tells the `virtual(8)` delivery agent to save the email into a Maildir called "supply" under `virtual_mailbox_base`.

Granted, this means having to update two files to add a new recipient. But if you were generating these files from a database, or using a database lookup, then that wouldn't really be a problem.

Note that I've aliased mail to `offline-comms` to get it piped to the application server. This might not work for you, depending on how you've integrated DBMail. Another way to do it is to alias incoming email into a special domain that is for archiving:

```
supply@emails.example.com   supply@emails.example.com, supply@archive.example.com
```

Then have the virtual domain `emails.example.com` fed to your dbmail transport (e.g. using the `transports` map to simply map `emails.example.com` to `dbmail-lmtp:`), and the `archive.example.com` domain delivered using the `virtual` transport to get saved to local mail.

Hope that helps!